# How to access @RequestBody before @PostMapping is called?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-web

I want to create an interceptor that writes a value to the `@RequestBody` by condition. But how can I intercept right before the `@PostMapping` is called by spring?

```
@RestController
public class PersonServlet {
    @PostMapping("/person")
    public void createPerson(@RequestBody Person p) {
        //business logic
    }

    class Person {
        String firstname, lastname;
        boolean getQueryParamPresent = false;   
    }
}
```

Then I send the `POST` body:

```
{
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe"
}
```

To url: `localhost:8080?_someparam=val`

My goal is to detect if any query param is present, and then directly write to the `Person` object that has been generated from the `POST` body.

I know I could achieve this easily within the servlet method. BUT as this is just an example, I want to apply this logic globally to *all* requests. Thus, for not having to repeat the same code call on every `POST` request, I'd like to have some kind of interceptor to write directly to the generated object (reflection would be fine).

But: is that possible? What method is executed by spring right before the `@PostMapping`? Maybe one could hook up there?

Comment: Seems like a good place for a MVC HandlerInterceptor.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: this article provides a good example. But you might have to do some manual json manipulation. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-interceptor-tutorial/

Comment: Well but the linked example is about `GET` requests, whose parameters can be easily read from the `HttpRequest`. But that's not the case for `POST`, which is my goal.

Comment: are you doing java 8?

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 1):

in spring the messageConverters are responsible for (de-)serializing json strings into objects. In your case this should be the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

You could overwrite it with your own implementation and overwrite the read method like this:

```
@Service
public class MyMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

@Autowired Provider<HttpServletRequest> request;

@Override
public Object read(Type type, @Nullable Class<?> contextClass, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
  Object result = super.read(type, contextClass, inputMessage);
  if (result instanceof Person) {
    HttpServletRequest req = request.get();
    // Do custom stuff with the request variables here...
  }
}
```

You can register than your own custom messageConverter by implementing your own WebMvcConfigurer and overwrite the configureMessageConverters method.

Couldn't try it here, but this should work!

Comment: Ok so i cannot hook the converter itself it seems.

Comment: Well this is one option to do this - another would be to register a custom deserializer like described here: 
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization
... but these are not managed by spring, so you would need another trick to get your request parameters.